# It was the last time + past / past perfect / present perfect

Tags: tense

Here's a context.

I met one of my friend, Jungsu, 2 years ago, but after that I haven't met him until now. Then, is it possible that I write like...

> 1. It was the last time that I met him 2 years ago.
> 2. It was the last time that I had met him 2 years ago.
> 3. It was the last time that I've met him 2 years ago.

And, plus..

> a. It was 2 years ago that I met him last.
>
> b. It was 2 years ago that I've met him last.

Which one is the most commonly used one?

Comment: *It was...* is a storyteller's way of saying this; in normal conversation, we'd say simply "The last time I saw him was two years ago".  BTW, by convention, we spell out the word "two" when writing.  With bigger numbers we can use the arabic numerals. http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/qanda/data/faq/topics/Numbers.html?page=1  It's not grammar, just a matter of style.

Answer (score 2):

In examples 1-3, we would say:

> The last time (that) I met/saw him was two years ago.

Similarly, rather than using a duration of time (two years) we could use the "point" in time:

> The last time (that) I met/saw him was in 2013.

Regarding your a and b examples, we would use simple past (a):

> It was two years ago that I last met/saw him.
>   I last met/saw him two years ago. (This one sounds more natural to me.)